# excel copying string found from cell one to a new cell

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula

I have a formulas that is currently only returning true/false, I wanted to improvise it instead of returning true/false, can I get the string that is found and copy it to another cell?

here is the formula that I use :

```
=NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B2))))))
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(D2:D21)/SIGN(SEARCH(D2:D21, B2)), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: it works but when I try to drag the formula the range compare changed and the rest of the row are comparing to the wrong row :( =INDEX(D:D;AGGREGATE(15; 6; ROW(D2:D21)/SIGN(SEARCH(D2:D21; B2)); 1))  D2 to D21 is the range of words of need to compare @jeeped

Comment: I guess you should make some of the cell range addresses absolute instead of relative.

Comment: I am not an expert in the formulas, so I am really not sure which part are you mentioning..

Comment: That is not 'expert' information;in fact, far from it. It is something everyone who ever types a formula into Excel needs to know.